# porting django app to GoogleAppEngine to deploy on appspot.com

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I wanted to port my `django app` to run on `GoogleAppEngine` and deploy this on `appspot.com`.In my django app I am using `postgres` as db to store user info,sothat user login /registration is possible.

I came across [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django#porting) about `porting django to appengine`.
It mentions that you need to use `Google Cloud SQL backend` .[This article](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing) says that it comes with a price from `june12th` onwards.

So,it seems that, to I have to pay to deploy even a non commercial application? Or is there some way I can do this without using cloud sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with django-nonrel, it requires a few modifications but it worked. [Here is a guide on how to set up.](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) After it worked for me, I realized Heroku was easier to set-up and maintain, so my other apps went straight to heroku.